# backbone marionette logic and view reuse

Tags: backbone.js, module, marionette

I'm just on my way getting into Marionette. I've already had a backbone project so I just have to learn the additional stuff which appears to be a bit difficult. But maybe I'm just wrong in structuring my application.

So I've my App which starts the application with `new Marionette.Application();`.
On the next level I have modules oder sub-apps with controllers and their views/regions/templates/layouts depending on what I want to render. So much for that.

How do I reuse some elements?

For example I need to code a Teaser in various version ([image|text] , [image|text|image] ,...). Is it possible to have a base teaser module and all other teaser versions just inherit (and extend) from the base teaser? I know that views can inherit from views and so on BUT I want to declare the teaser modul (and all teaser versions) just once! All that in order to use them in the application context not just in the modul context.

At the end for example I have the app with 3 sub-apps and all the sub-apps use a different kind of the teaser. All three teasers inherit from my base teaser.

Not easy to discribe but I hope you get the idea.

**EDIT** okay for everybody else who ran in this structure problem. [Brian Mann cleared up my confusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWr7x9wk6_c&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Marionette there is a function for that: http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.functions.html#marionetteextend

Comment: great thanks thats how is can solve the problem with the teasers. How do i use them in different pages. If I have a module teaser and a Module Slider. How can I print them on the same route? I think I'm on a oneway. The Module in Marionette is more like a namespace right? How can I realize "Modules" as UI elements or in general how can I create UI elements like a teaser that I can use in all Modules of the application?